# using split based on multiple delimiters and different empty lines length

Tags: java, string, replace

I have some .dat file that contains the following:

```
<D,E>   200  200    799  1220   No   [<805,1380,Voltage,3,2>]
<A,C>   300  300    415  1230  Yes   [<417,1340,Voltage,3,0><415,1230,Current,3,1>]
<D,B>   200  200    799  122    No   [<80,137,Voltage,3,2>]
  .
  .
```

I would like to have the each line, the content of the third element; that is 200 on the first line and 300 on the second line and 200 on the third line. I would also like to have the 0 and the 1 (I would like to add them) on the second line and the 2 on the first and third lines.

I tried this

```
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {
            line = line.replace(" ", "|");
            line = line.replace("||", "");
            System.out.println(line);

            String[] temp = line.split("|");
            String temp1 = "";
            String temp2 = "";

            //System.out.println(temp[52]);
            if (temp.length == 55) {
                temp1 = temp[11] + temp[12] + temp[13];
                temp2 = temp[52];


            } else if (temp.length==52){
                int len = temp.length;
                temp1 = temp[11] + temp[12] + temp[13];
                temp2 = temp[temp.length - 3];

            }
```

}

For the first line it works, it also works when the temp.length has the same size; however, my line do not always have the same length. How can I split my line in a nice way so that I can have the elements I need.

Comment: `System.out.println(line.split("\\s+")[2]);`

Comment: *I would also like to have the 0 and the 1 (I would like to add them)* - add the numbers as integers? Or floats? Or just concatenate them as strings?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/M1CFuz

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew, it is perfect. It works perfectly. Please put it as a solution so that I can accept it.

Comment: Posted, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first split the string with whitespaces (using `.split("\\s+")`) and then use a simple regex like `([0-9]+)>` to extract chunks of digits before a `>`):

```
// Init the regex here
String rx = "([0-9]+)>";

// Then the part where you read the lines
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    String[] chunks = line.split("\\s+"); // Split with whitespace
    if (chunks.length > 2) { // chunks[2] = 200 / 300 values
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line); // Init Matcher to find all numbers at the end of >
        int val = 0;
        while (m.find()) {  // Find multiple occurrences numbers before >
            val += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); // Group 1 contains the number, summing up
        }
        res.add(chunks[2]);
        res.add(Integer.toString(val));
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
}
System.out.println(res); // => [200, 2, 300, 1, 200, 2]
```

See the [IDEONE Java demo](http://ideone.com/M1CFuz)